# Laravel/Livewire unable to call function from JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function on  `pdfParse.js` from a Livewire component.

I need to use `pdf-js`, a JavaScript library which I'm packing with Mix (Webpack), as I do with the whole script. The file gets delivered to the browser without any problem, but I'm unable to make it available to Livewire and be called from a `<script>` tag.

I've tried [this solution from Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/how-to-execute-function-in-appjs-from-a-livewire-component-with-alpinejs?page=0&replyId=142439), but I can't get the function to be added to `window` variable on `app.js` and make it available on the browser (log shows it as undefined on the browser).

How can I get my function to be added to `window` or how can I call a function of a JavaScript file within Livewire?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I'm trying to call a function from my blade template (html):

```html
<button onclick="myFunction();">Button</button>
```

This function is defined on a JavaScript file

```js
//myFile.js
function myFunction(){...}
```

which I add to the header of my main layout

```html
<script src="{{mix('js/myFile.js')}}"></script>
```

Then I check that the file is correctly bundled and delivered to the web browser.

When I try this, I get and undefined error on the console. I can't use [inline scripts](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts) on my livewire component because I have to use a JS library, bundling it with webpack.

I tried the solution of this [Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/how-to-execute-function-in-appjs-from-a-livewire-component-with-alpinejs?page=0&replyId=142439) and added my function to the window object at `app.js`:

```js
//app.js
´require('./bootstrap');

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

window.myFunction = function myFunction(){...}
```

and change the function call on my html

```html
<button onclick="window.myFunction();">Button</button>
```

but still nothing. Then I added a `console.log()` at `app.js`, but it doesn't executes, so I don't know how to make it run and be able to call my functions from livewire.

Edit 2:

I'm leaving here the compiled code:

```js
(self["webpackChunk"] = self["webpackChunk"] || []).push([["/js/myFile"],{

/***/ "./resources/js/myFile.js":
/*!******************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/js/myFile.js ***!
  \******************************/
/***/ (() => {

function myFunction() {
  console.log("hola");
}

window.myFunction= myFunction;
alert("A");

/***/ })

},
/******/ __webpack_require__ => { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = (moduleId) => (__webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId))
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = (__webpack_exec__("./resources/js/myFunction.js"));
/******/ }
]);
```

Nothing of this code gets executed at the browser.

Comment: you should provide more explicitly what you tried/have, some code.

Comment: It's hard to say anything here without seeing the code you have,  with explicit description

Comment: Have you used `npm run build` or `npm run dev` or whatever your command is after editing `app.js`? In a default Laravel/Livewire install, directly editing that file is a first step, but not the only step.

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling the code with ```npm run watch```. What steps should I follow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open up the resulting app.js in the browser. Do you see your `window.myFunction` line in there? Is it possibly cached?

Comment: Yes, it shows at my browser and it's updated. I think that the problem is that my compiled code is inside a webpack chunk, and it never gets to execute. I'm leaving the compiled code on the new edit.